# Why is Redis not responding?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, backend, node-redis

I'm trying to run Redis in my node backend. The code runs fine until it gets to any Redis command, at which point it just stops. No error message or anything e.g.

```
const client = redis.createClient()
client.connect().then(() => redisTest())

const redisTest = async () => {
    console.log("running redis test...")
    try {
        client.set("test","val", function(err) {
            if (err) {
               // Something went wrong
               console.error("error");
            } else {
                client.get("test", function(err, value) {
                     if (err) {
                         console.error("error");
                     } else {
                         console.log("Worked: " + value)
                     }
                })
            }
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Redis error", error)
    }
}

client.on('error', err => console.log('Redis Client Error', err));
```

The console logs "running redis test..." and then just stops (at the very least I'd expect an error message). Redis CLI is running fine, I'm able to get and set values and I've verified the port number. I've also tried

```
async client.connect()
```

and

```
(async () => {
    await client.connect()
})
```

Both of which throw errors.

Any suggestions on how I could resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This returns val

```js
const client = redis.createClient();

const connectRedis = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    client.connect()
    client.on('connect', () => {
      console.log('Connected to Redis server...');
      resolve();
    });
    client.on('error', (err) => {
      console.error('Error connecting to Redis:', err);
      reject(err);
    });
  });
};

const redisTest = async () => {
  try {
    console.log("running redis test...");
    await client.set("test", "val");
    const value = await client.get("test");
    console.log("Worked: " + value);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Redis error", error);
  } finally {
    client.quit(); // Close the Redis client after the test is complete.
  }
};

// Usage: Connect to Redis first and then execute the test
connectRedis()
  .then(redisTest)
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error("Error in Redis test:", err);
    client.quit(); // Close the Redis client if there is an error during connection or test.
  });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).